# Use onBackPressed to save a file

Tags: android

I want to allow users to save a list of favourite items from a list, so I display the full list using a Listview with checkboxes, and the user will check or uncheck items in the list.

When the user presses the back button, I want to be able to save the checked items out to a separate file on the SD card.

I'm using the following method in my Activity:

```
@Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }
```

However, the list that I create within my OnCreate method is not available within the onBackPressed method - ie it's out of scope.

If I try and pass the list into the onBackPressed method as follows:

```
@Override
  public void onBackPressed(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> checked_list) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }
```

Then I get the error:

"The method onBackPressed(ArrayList>) of type SetFavourites must override or implement a supertype method" and Eclipse prompts to remove the @Override.

But when I do this, then the onBackPressed method never gets called.

How can I pass variables into the onBackPressed method so that I can perform actions on data within my Activity before exiting?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a variable in the class' scope, ie outside onCreate().

```
class Example {
    int mVisible = 0;

    void onCreate() {
        int notVisible = mVisible;
    }

    void onBackPressed() {
        mVisible = 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks - I need to go back & look at class theory again... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `@Override` to override a non-existent method. In other words `onBackPressed(ArrayList<...> foo)` is not an existing method of the `Activity` class.

To access your list declare it as an instance member of your `Activity`...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> checked_list;

    // onCreate(...) here

    // onBackPressed() here

}
```

Comment: You've actually highlighted a fundamental weakness in my Java knowledge, LOL, and your answer has solved more than one of my problems, so thanks for that!